# i want to compile all c++ files from different folders using makefile?

Tags: unix, object, compilation, makefile

i have 4 folders obj ,src ,inc,exe so src folder contains .cpp file , inc folder has .h files after compilation object file should go in obj folder and .exe file should go in exe folder ?
anyone can know about this 
please please please help me ?

Comment: You are asking how to write a moderately complex makefile. Do you know how to write a simple makefile?

Comment: ya i know how to write simple makefile

Comment: if you know about my question so please tell me ?

Comment: can you show us what you tried, where exactly your problem is. Nobody likes to just write a full makefile for you

Comment: You want a makefile that will do half a dozen things; pick *one* you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are using gcc compiler, you easily achieve it by:

a) Get a common makefile template from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/panruochen/dragoneye/master/common_Makefile
And put common_Makefile into your source directory.
b) Write a small Makefile looking like below

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS    := -ggdb -O3
EXTRA_CFLAGS    += -Wall
DEFINES         := -DMY_DEFINE
SRCS            := src/
INCS            := inc/
TARGET_TYPE     := EXE
TARGET          := exe/foo.exe
LIBS            := -lpthread
OBJ_DIR         := objs
SRC_EXTS        := cpp c

include common_Makefile
```

c) Run make to finish compilations.